# I am not using nor with neither is that fine or it is grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar, neither-nor

Sometimes I see that I can't fit "neither & nor" together or it looks like it won't sound correct.

So, would I be grammatically incorrect if I don't use `nor` with `neither` in the same sentence?

These posts couldnt help me:
[Using "neither" without "nor"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194041/using-neither-without-nor?rq=1)

["They do not agree --neither with ... nor with ...": Wrong?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154392/they-do-not-agree-neither-with-nor-with-wrong)

[What is the correct way to use "neither" and "nor" in a sentence together?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30075/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-neither-and-nor-in-a-sentence-together)

```
Hey Perry, 

I am not able to see payment box neither I can put the new one here.
```

Comment: I already went to those links. I don't see any logic/concept how to use it over there. Secondly, my situation in which I want it to fit in didn't seem to be working.

Comment: 'I am not able to see the payment box; neither can I put the new one here.' is fine if rather starchy/formal. The negative statement  (to 'box') licenses the lone 'neither', but the inversion is then forced. A comma + 'and', a semi-colon, or two sentences are necessary punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter if you don't use `nor` but in that case, the sentence should be framed like :

```
Hey Perry, 

I am not able to see the payment box nor can I put the new one here.
```

Comment: ...*the* payment box *nor* can i...     imho. I think the 'neither' is weird and doesn't really fit (may even be related to either "the payment box" or "the new one ")

Comment: @bukwyrm yep..sorry nor was what I was trying to post.Edited!! Thanks..

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but is there a concept behind it? Why is it fine if I don't use `nor`?

Comment: "I can't use that (n)either" works, as does "I can't use this nor can i use that" as does "I cant use this, and neither that" - but if there is no ", and",  "nor " is the expected word: "I can't use this nor that" or: "I **can** use neither this nor that"

Comment: While I agree with your rephrasing, you need to edit your answer. As it stands, it reads like *it doesn't matter if you don't use* ***nor*** *but in that case, . . . you should use* ***nor***. A more correct expression would be *if you use only* ***neither*** or ***nor*** *, it should be . . .* ;)